# Valores duplicados en power bi donde solo se quiere dejar el del mes mas antiguo

Tags: powerbi

Un numero de contrato es un valor unico para cada colaborador. Pero si realizo un buscarV entre el #colaborador y las veces que el colaborador a  visitado la tienda me va a salir ese numero contrato repetido ya que el colaborador visito la tienda en diferentes meses y yo solo quiero que ese numero se asigne a la primera visita del cliente, es decir el primer mes que visito la tienda (mes mas antiguo)

Ejemplo de como lo tengo
#Colaborador Mes_VIsita       Contrato
12345         Septiembre      2222222
12345         Octubre         2222222
12345         Noviembre       2222222

Ejemplo como lo quiero
#Colaborador Mes_Visita       Contrato
12345         Septiembre      2222222
12345         Octubre         0
12345         Noviembre       0